# Портятся цвета SVG

Tags: html, svg

Хочу добавить к себе на страницу SVG-шку, вставляю ее svg-код в html, и получается так, что у нее испорчены некоторые цвета. Такое происходит, если у меня на странице хотя бы две svg, при этом та, что добавлена раньше, имеет нормальные цвета, а новая испорчена. Что происходит и как это исправить? Я знаю, что можно добавлять как img, но тогда я не смогу взаимодействовать с этой свгшкой.

Вот пример, на первом фото нормальная картинка, а на втором испорченная.
[image: Вот так должна выглядеть эта картинка]

[image: Вот так не должно быть]

```
Код можно посмотреть тут: https://jsfiddle.net/gv6ok7Lc/
```

Comment: Смотрю ваш файл, там три знака после десятичной запятой. Попробуйте его оптимизировать, как вам советовали в этом [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1265584/28748) в прошлый раз после оптимизации всё заработало.

Comment: пробовал, бесполезно.